# Is the response stream not disposed until read to end?

Tags: c#, wcf

An example contract of a **Streamed** service:

```
public interface IFileService
{
    Stream Download(int id);
}
```

A sample client:

```
var proxy = ...
using(var responseStream = proxy.Download(666))
{
     while(true)
     {
          var someBytes = //responseStream.Read(...)
          if(someBytes[0] == 11)
              return;//here is called dispose by using statement, but stream will call Read in it's Dispose method!
     }
}
```

So, yeah, if you decide to analyze just a few bytes from start of your 10GB file and leave at this point - you will be doomed to wait until WCF CloseTimeout expires, or until you read entire 10GB file, according to [this source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/SingletonConnectionReader.cs,ec4831684278959d).

How to tell WCF to stop reading the entire stream to end without cheap tricks of "zerofying" the **closeTimeout** option?

Comment: Is that link correct? It refers to the `SingletonConnectionReader` abstract class which does not inherit from `Stream`?

Comment: It is reader which causes stream "suckup".